# Has any Western country in the (say) last 25 years threaten to retaliate militarily when a vessel not navigating under its flag was attacked?

Tags: armed-conflict, western-world, flag, law-of-the-sea, maritime-security

Relating to the various attacks/seizures at sea in recent years, it [seems](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-49053383) to me Western countries draw a line between vessels formally navigating under flag of country X and those just owned by companies based in country X.

Has any Western country threatened to militarily retaliate when a ship owned by its nationals, but [flying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_convenience) the flag of some other country was attacked?

(Iran and/or Israel [might](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/03/26/world/middleeast/israel-iran-shadow-war.html) have more or less [in]formally done the latter in their 'shadow war', so I'm asking about [other] Western countries.)

Comment: First thought,  there have been military actions undertaken against Somali paramilitaries that engaged in Piracy around East Africa, -- not quite the same situation, but the flag of convenience might not be the main thing, and countries will act to protect their interest on the high seas.

Comment: @JamesK: yeah, I thought about that. Wasn't there some UNSC resolution about it though?

Comment: Pretty sure that there have been multiple regional joint anti-piracy operations. The one against Somali pirates even had China on board, IIRC. U.S. law has been clear since the 1700s that piracy against any commercial ship on the high seas is contrary to the law of nations and can be dealt with by the U.S. Navy. That's what the Tripoli reference in the Marines' Hymn is about. https://www.marineband.marines.mil/Audio-Resources/The-Marines-Hymn/